# C# and modbus/tcp

Tags: c#, tcpclient, modbus

I need to read some data from a rs485 device. It is connected to a [Aport-211W](http://www.artila.com/p_aport.html#Aport-211W) and this one is connected to my local network. This device opens a server on port 502 and this is the rs485 port of the device I wanted to read. The protocoll is modbus.

My first try was to link this mobus/tcp to a local COM Port on my computer with [this Software](http://www.fabulatech.com/serial-port-redirector.html) and read everything through it. But I dont want to use an other software for this and now my question is: How can i directly connect from a C# program to the modbus/tcp server and read data out?

I have already found some libraries but none of them is able to connect to the device. I have closed the Serial Port Redirector because it blocks the communication. Has anybody done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Aport-211W is just a gateway between your MODBUS device (probably MODBUS RTU) and network. It does not do any protocol conversion, which means that you have MODBUS RTU over TCP and not plain MODBUS TCP protocol. These are different protocols, and you need to adjust according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write on yourself if you want, that way u can contol the stuff ur self and will be bespoke.

mostly, it would be Modbus RTU over TCP from the Slave.

Just create sockets to communicate with the Aport as they communicate through TCP.